# React Native ScrollView scrollTo spring animation

Tags: react-native, react-animated, react-native-scrollview

I am using React Native's `ScrollView`'s `scrollTo` method to animate the scroll view. How can I make this animation spring loaded, as in `Animated.spring` (without the use of a 3rd party library)?

Answer (score 2):

Track the scroll position

```
<ScrollView
    ref={(ref) => { this.scrollView = ref; }}
    onScroll={(event) => {
        this.scrollY = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    }}
    scrollEventThrottle={16}
>
```

And then

```
scrollTo(y) {
    if (!this.scrollY) this.scrollY = 0;
    const animatedValue = new Animated.Value(this.scrollY);
    const id = animatedValue.addListener(({ value }) => {
        this.scrollView.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: value, animated: false });
    });
   Animated.spring(animatedValue, { toValue: y }).start(() => { animatedValue.removeListener(id); /* finished callback */ });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't animate at all